# Is c++11 operator[] equivalent to emplace on map insertion?

Tags: c++11, dictionary, emplace

For C++11, is there still a performance difference between the following?

(for `std::map<Foo, std::vector<Bar> >` as an example)

```
map[key] = myVector and map.emplace(key, myVector)
```

The part I'm not figuring out is the exact internal of operator[]. My understanding so far has been (when key doesn't exist):

1. Create a new key and the associated empty default vector in place inside the map
2. Return the reference of the associated empty vector
3. Assign myVector to the reference???

The point 3 is the part I couldn't understand, how can you assign a new value to a reference in the first place?

Though I cannot sort through point 3 I think somehow there's just a copy/move required. Assuming C++11 will be smart enough to know it's gonna be a move operation, is this whole "[]" assignment then already cheaper than insert()? Is it almost equivalent to emplace()? ---- default construction and move content over, versus construct vector with content directly in place?

Comment: Is your question specific to `map` being of type `std::map<Foo, std::vector<Bar>>` or for any kind of map?

Comment: Yeah it's that, I will update the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a *lot* of differences between the two.

If you use `operator[]`, then the `map` will *default construct* the value. The return value from `operator[]` will be this default constructed object, which will then use `operator=` to assign to it.

If you use `emplace`, the `map` will directly construct the value with the parameters you provide.

So the `operator[]` method will always use two-stage construction. If the default constructor is slow, or if copy/move construction is faster than copy/move assignment, then it could be problematic.

However, `emplace` will not *replace* the value if the provided key already exists. Whereas `operator[]` followed by `operator=` will always replace the value, whether there was one there or not.

There are other differences too. If copying/moving throws, `emplace` guarantees that the `map` *will not be changed*. By contrast, `operator[]` will always insert a default constructed element. So if the later copy/move assignment fails, then the `map` has already been changed. That key will exist with a default constructed `value_type`.

Really, performance is not the first thing you should be thinking about when deciding which one to use. You need to focus first on whether it has the desired behavior.

C++17 will [provide `insert_or_assign`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert_or_assign), which has the effect of `map[] = v;`, but with the exception safety of `insert/emplace`.

> how can you assign a new value to a reference in the first place?

It's fundamentally no different from assigning to *any* non-`const` reference:

```
int i = 5;
int &j = i;
j = 30;
i == 30; //This is true.
```