# Is it correct to use std::map::emplace with a function returning a shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, stl, shared-ptr

If I have some function that returns a `std::shared_ptr<T>`, how should I insert the result of that function call in a `std::map<U, std::shared_ptr<T>>`: with `insert` and `make_pair` or just `emplace`?

Let's say I already know there isn't a duplicate key, and that I'm single threaded.

```
std::shared_ptr<Foo> bar() {
   return std::make_shared<Foo>();
}

std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Foo>> my_map;

// Which makes more sense?
my_map.emplace("key", bar());
// or
my_map.insert(make_pair("key", bar()));
```

Does RVO work with `std::map::emplace`?

Comment: Both options will probably compile to the same assembly.

Comment: I had a quick look on godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/4J-O4_ there are some differences, but I can't tell if they are significant

Comment: I think that would be helpful, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14816409/moving-an-object-into-a-map

Comment: emplace does in-place insertion and avoids an unnecessary copy of object

Comment: @Hiroki Yes, I think that is the same, thanks! `bar()` gives me an r-value reference, which will be forwarded to `pair`'s ctor, which in turn will call the move-ctor for `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is correct.

---

### RVO

**I think that RVO should work fine as long as it is implemented in your compiler**, because `bar()` returns temporal object and the compiler knows what object is to be returned from `bar()`.
Also, in C++17 and over, RVO is guarnteed in such a case.

[Is RVO (Return Value Optimization) applicable for all objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596183/is-rvo-return-value-optimization-applicable-for-all-objects)

[What are copy elision and return value optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization)

---

### emplace vs. insert ([DEMO](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zMA1pWOqLc160pPU))

**std::map::emplace**

In

```
my_map.emplace("key", bar());
```

, RVO replaces `bar()` with `std::make_shared<Foo>()` and `std::shared_ptr<Foo>` is created.
Then it is forwarded and **move-ctor** of `std::shared_ptr<Foo>` is called **just once** at in-place construction of new element of `my_map`.

**std::map::insert with std::make_pair**

In

```
my_map.insert(make_pair("key", bar()));
```

, RVO again replaces `bar()` with `std::make_shared<Foo>()`.

Next, from 20.3.2 of [N3337](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents), C++11 with minor errors corrected, the class template of `std::pair` is

> ```
> namespace std{
>   template<class T1, class T2>
>   struct pair
>   {
>     typedef T1 first_type;
>     typedef T2 second_type;
>     T1 first;
>     T2 second;
>     ...
>     template<class U, class V> pair(U&& x, V&& y);
>     ...
>   }
> }
> ```

where template ctor is

> ```
> template<class U, class V> pair(U&& x, V&& y);
> ```
>
> *Effects*: The constructor initializes `first` with `std::forward<U>(x)` and `second` with `std::forward<V>(y)`.

In addition, from 20.3.3

> ```
> template<class T1, class T2>
> pair<V1, V2> make_pair(T1&& x, T2&& y);
> ```
>
> *Returns*: `pair<V1, V2>(std::forward<T1>(x), std::forward<T2>(y))`;...

Thus typical implementation of `std::make_pair` for this definition is considered like this:

```
namespace std{
  template<class T1, class T2>
  inline pair<typename decay<T1>::type, typename decay<T2>::type>
  make_pair(T1&& x, T2&& y)
  {
    return pair<typename decay<T1>::type,
                typename decay<T2>::type>
                (std::forward<T1>(x), std::forward<T2>(y));
  }
}
```

and RVO will again work for `std::make_pair`.
In fact, the number of move-ctor call is incremented by just one if we compile [DEMO](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zMA1pWOqLc160pPU) with C++14 and a compiler option "-fno-elide-constructors" which desables g++'s RVO.

Therefore in `std::make_pair("key", bar())`, I expect the following senario:

- 1) RVO replaces `bar()` with `std::make_shared<Foo>()`,
- 2) RVO also replaces `std::make_pair` with `std::pair::pair`,
- 3) `std::shared_prtr<Foo>` is created and then it is forwarded to `std::pair::pair`,
- 4) `std::shared_prtr<Foo>` is created as an element `second` by **move-ctor**.

Finally, `std::map::insert` is also overloaded for r-values:

```
// since C++11
template< class P >
std::pair<iterator,bool> insert( P&& value );
```

Here again

- 5) **move-ctor** of `std::shared_prtr<Foo>` is called.

In summary, I expect

```
my_map.insert(make_pair("key", bar()));
```

calls move-ctor of `std::shared_ptr<Foo>` **twice**.

**My answer**

Since in both cases no copies of the `std::shared_ptr<Foo>` are done at all and almost same number of move-ctors are called, their performance would be almost same.

[Moving an object into a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14816409/moving-an-object-into-a-map)

[insert vs emplace vs operator[] in c++ map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17172080/insert-vs-emplace-vs-operator-in-c-map)

[Is c++11 operator[] equivalent to emplace on map insertion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176770/is-c11-operator-equivalent-to-emplace-on-map-insertion)

---

### Note 1,  universal reference

In C++11 and over, both left and right argument of `std::make_pair` are what Scott Meyers calls [universal reference](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers), that is, they can accept both l-value and r-value:

```
// until C++11
template< class T1, class T2 >
std::pair<T1,T2> make_pair( T1 t, T2 u );

// since C++11
template< class T1, class T2 >
std::pair<V1,V2> make_pair( T1&& t, T2&& u );
```

Thus if we pass l-value to `std::make_pair`, then copy-ctor of `std::shared_ptr<Foo>` is called as a result of the universal reference.

---

### Note 2,  std::map::try_emplace

`std::map::emplace` always constructs new element of `my_map` even if the key already exists.
If the key already exists, these new instances are destroyed.
But since C++17, we get

```
template <class... Args>
pair<iterator, bool> try_emplace(key_type&& k, Args&&... args);
```

This function does not construct `args` if the key `k` already exists in the container.
Although we already know there isn't a duplicate key in the present problem, if we don't know whether there is a duplicate key or not, this `std::map::try_emplace` would be preferred.

[Is there any reason to use std::map::emplace() instead of try_emplace() in C++1z?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46046828/is-there-any-reason-to-use-stdmapemplace-instead-of-try-emplace-in-c1z)